# Problems installing revtex - 'revtex4-2.cls not found'

Tags: packages, installing, revtex

I am using TeX Maker with texlife on Windows 10 and I want to install the revtex package (as I want to use the APS style in LaTeX). I followed the [description here](https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#u2) and downloaded the corresponding zip file ("revtex4-2-tds.zip") and unpacked the archive. Afterwards, following the description, I looked for the local tree of my TeX distribution, which I found at "C:\Users\myname.texlive2017".
As there was no "texmf-local" sub-directory I created it and copied all files from the unzipped folder in this new folder.
Once I run a test file with "\documentclass[preprint,...]{revtex4-2}" (as suggested in a "how to get started" document) I get the error message 'revtex4-2.cls not found'.

So, obviously I am doing something wrong. I've tried a couple of other things but non of them solved my problem. Also, I have searched for others having this problem, but I only found one case where it occured on a Linux system and many other descriptions of exactly what I did. I am quite new to LaTeX, so I do not have much experience in installing additional stuff, hence I am grateful for any hint/help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You seem to have a very strange installation and a very old one. Probably better to install texlive 2020 instead, 4-2 is already included

Comment: oh, great - thank you!